# What's does "These six will gladly you attend" mean?

Tags: meaning

> The best six doctors anywhere
> And no one can deny it
> Are sunshine, water, rest, and air
> Exercise and diet.
> These six will gladly you attend
> If only you are willing
> Your mind they'll ease
> Your will they'll mend
> And charge you not a shilling.

Nursery rhyme quoted by Wayne Fields

Does "These six will gladly you attend" maeans you will gladly visit these doctors, or does it mean they will gladly help?

Comment: It looks like a mock-archaic verse, if it is indeed written by a contemporary author.  In the language of past times it means "These six will gladly attend on you" i.e. make a home visit, which doctors seldom have the time to do nowadays.

Comment: Here *attend* means take care of, rather like *tend to*. And *you* is its complement. So the sentence means that those six elements will do you a lot of good if you take advantage of them.

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum - Surely _gladly_ implies that the elements are still being personified as 'doctors'?

Comment: @KateBunting, metaphorically? Yes, by all means.

Comment: It appears to have been written early in the 20th century (1919) by someone who hadn't read any modern poetry.  https://www.google.com/books/edition/American_Journal_of_Public_Health/CMNBAQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=the+best+six+doctors+anywhere&pg=PA730-IA1&printsec=frontcover

Comment: It seems quite common to include such mock-archaisms in children's verse. Certainly there is a lot in Belloc's Cautionary Tales for Children (1920) as well as RL Stevenson's Child's Garden of Verses (1885) and lots of other similar verse. Maybe it's supposed to be cute, or is just done for rhymes.

Comment: It's a grammatical but highly unnatural form used here only to preserve the *iambic metre*.

Answer (score 1):

The main thing that might be confusing the meaning is that the normal word order has been inverted. It would be more standard as "These six will gladly attend you." And the main reason is simply for poetic purposes, because the author wanted to rhyme *mend*, and fit the metre of stressed syllables.

It caused you some confusion about who is attending whom. As you know, English uses word order to show subject and object; in the sentences "Bill hit Bob" and "Bob hit Bill," a different person gets hit in each. The reason we can still figure out "These six will gladly you attend" (aside from context) is that the object (*you*) still comes after at least one part of the verb "will attend." If it had said "These six you will gladly attend," then it really might have seemed like it meant you will go to the doctors.